# Playing audio files sequentially in HTML5

Tags: audio, autoplay, php-5.5

**How can I use PHP to play audio files sequentially?**

I have multiple audio files I would like to play sequentially instead of simultaneously. I'm using code similar to the following:

```
<audio controls autoplay='true'>
  <source src="sample1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<audio controls autoplay='true'>
  <source src="sample2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I need **sample2** to play 5 seconds after **sample1** has finished playing. In both cases no user interaction should be involved.

### Update

I thought this should be as simple as using consecutive function calls but that didn't work. I began looking into and using the sleep() function using the example code below:

```
print "<br>Line1";
sleep(10);
print "<br>Line2";
```

This just delays the entire script by 10 seconds and prints both statements instead of one after the other. It's the same with the audio files, which is ultimately the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

after trying several scrips I found, that is what worked for me

```js
    var audionameslist = `
        audiolib/1.mp3,
        audiolib/2.mp3,
        audiolib/3.mp3
    `;
    var audionamesarray = audionameslist.split(',');
    var audio = new Audio(audionamesarray[0]);
        
    audio.src=audionamesarray[0];
    audio.play();
       
    index=1;
    audio.onended = function() {
        if(index < audionamesarray.length){
            audio.src=audionamesarray[index];
            audio.play();
            index++;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered before.
You don't need any PHP it is all in the HTML5 APIs.

The player has an ended event `ended`. Just change the `src` attrib after the ended is fired.
The element will then load the 'next song'.

[Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025051/play-multiple-audio-files-sequentially-or-randomly-in-background-using-html5-and)

**FYI: I just copied your title and searched it in Google and voila! I found this SO question...**

Answer (score -1):

You could create a small JS something like below. Just pass in the Audio element ID's to the function and it should play it sequentially. Thank you and all the best.

```
function playAll(audioidlist) {
    var audioarray = audioidlist.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < audioarray.length; i++) {
        var audio = document.getElementById(audioarray[i]);
        audio.play();
        while (!audio.ended) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes! Use a callback instead of an infinite loop!